# Oracle SQL indexed query 100% cpu usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running a relatively simple query

```
SELECT * FROM confirm_v c
JOIN person p ON c.created_by=p.id
INNER JOIN invoice_confirm ic ON ic.confirm_id=c.id
WHERE c.id = (SELECT id FROM 
                 (SELECT c2.id FROM confirm c2
                  JOIN invoice_confirm ic2 ON ic2.confirm_id=c2.id
                  WHERE ic2.invoice_id=11954081
                  AND c2.previous=0
                  AND c2.canceled=0
                  AND c2.confirm_type='INVOICE'
                  ORDER BY c2.id)
              WHERE rownum=1);
```

which results in 100% cpu usage by the rdb. The `confirm_type` is a `varchar2(50 char)`, the rest are `number(10)` if it means anything.

The `invoice_confirm` and `confirm` tables are covered by indices and there are no full table scans visible in the execution plan for this query.

This query isn't executed a lot, but accounts for nearly 100% of total cpu usage. Any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT:
The explain plan in text from for the query.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ...
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
Plan hash value: 1705859247


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                      | Name                        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                               |                             |     1 |    69 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                                  |                             |     1 |    69 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                                 |                             |     1 |    69 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                                |                             |     1 |    57 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                               |                             |     1 |    30 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | CONFIRM                     |     1 |    24 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | PK_CONFIRM                  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        COUNT STOPKEY                           |                             |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |         VIEW                                   |                             |     4 |    52 |    27   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |          SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY                 |                             |     4 |   132 |    27   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                         |                             |     4 |   132 |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                        |                             |    11 |   132 |    26   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| INVOICE_CONFIRM             |     3 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | FKI_INVOICE_CONFIRM_INVOICE |     2 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | PK_CONFIRM                  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | CONFIRM                     |     1 |    21 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | FKI_INVOICE_CONFIRM_CONFIRM |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | PERSON                      |     1 |    27 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                         | PK_KASUTAJA                 |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | FKI_INVOICE_CONFIRM_CONFIRM |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                  | INVOICE_CONFIRM             |     1 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("CONFIRM"."ID"= (SELECT "ID" FROM  (SELECT "C2"."ID" "ID" FROM "INVOICE_CONFIRM" "IC2","CONFIRM" "C2" 
              WHERE "IC2"."CONFIRM_ID"="C2"."ID" AND "C2"."CANCELED"=0 AND "C2"."PREVIOUS"=0 AND "C2"."CONFIRM_TYPE"='INVOICE' AND 
              "IC2"."INVOICE_ID"=11954081 ORDER BY "C2"."ID") "from$_subquery$_006" WHERE ROWNUM=1))
   7 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   9 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
  13 - access("IC2"."INVOICE_ID"=11954081)
  14 - access("IC2"."CONFIRM_ID"="C2"."ID")
  15 - filter("C2"."CANCELED"=0 AND "C2"."PREVIOUS"=0 AND "C2"."CONFIRM_TYPE"='INVOICE')
  16 - access("IC"."CONFIRM_ID"="CONFIRM"."ID")
  18 - access("CONFIRM"."CREATED_BY"="P"."ID")
  19 - access("IC"."CONFIRM_ID"="CONFIRM"."ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
   - 2 Sql Plan Directives used for this statement
```

Comment: What indexes do you have? How many rows (rough estimate) all four tables have? Also, please post the execution plan.

Comment: I doubt theres no full table scan seeing all those `!=` . It's not possible to change them by listing all possibilities but the ones you are searching ?

Comment: plan: https://imgur.com/a/4xsh4Rv

Comment: Indices on invoice_confirm.invoice_id, all ids. No index on those confirm.previous etc.

Comment: The plan is incomplete. Please include the **access** and **filter** notes.

Comment: Could you generate the plan in a text format using these two commands:  `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query` then `SELECT * FROM TABLE( dbms_xplan.display )`. This text version includes predicate information (printed at the bottom), there is no such information in the plan you have shown.

Comment: I edited the question and added the output for the explain plan.

Comment: I'd say that you do a sort (a CPU-intensive operation) for every `confirm_v` record you include in the result set. If the amount to sort is large, it will be CPU-intensive. BTW `order by` does full sorting in linear-log time, while `min` does just a full scan through the set in linear time; you could consider using it. To check if this is the case, try commenting out the `order by` part in the subquery and see if it runs faster.

Answer (score 0):

Gather optimizer statistics on the relevant tables and investigate why the statistics were missing.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CONFIRM');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'INVOICE_CONFIRM');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PERSON');
end;
/
```

Optimizer statistics are critical for Oracle to achieve good performance.  The note `dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)` implies that there are tables with missing optimizer statistics.  That should never happen unless the tables were created within the last day.

Oracle automatically gathers stale and missing statistics.  Check if the job is running with this query.  If there are no recent rows, ask your DBA to re-enable the task.

```
select *
from dba_optstat_operations
where operation like '%auto%'
order by start_time desc;
```

The autotask is good enough for most tables.  But if there's a large batch process that updates a lot of rows then the statistics should be manually collected as soon as the job is complete.